# Intellij-IDEA кодировка в android проекте (UTF and 1251)

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea, кодировка

вот уже несколько дней пытаюсь разобраться в том как правильно создать android проект в idea 12.1.6 (windows) **без кодировки:** windows-1251, тоесть полностью на UTF (8 || 16 || 32 сути не меняет)

в `idea\File\Settings\File Encodings` параметры IDE,Project,Properties Encoding установлены в UTF, но idea стабильно создаёт файлы в кодировке 1251 в

```
{PROJECT}\src\{Packages}\MyActivity.java //та что создаётся при создании проекта
{PROJECT}\gen\{Packages}\BuildConfig.java
{PROJECT}\gen\{Packages}\Manifest.java
{PROJECT}\gen\{Packages}\R.java

{USER}\.IntelliJIdea12\system\compile-server\{PROJECT}\targets\java-production   \{PROJECT}\android\generated_sources\aapt\{Packages}\R.java
{USER}\.IntelliJIdea12\system\compile-server\{PROJECT}\targets\java-production\{PROJECT}\android\generated_sources\build_config\{Packages}\BuildConfig.java
```

в результате чего получаю геморой и ошибки (связанные с использованием двух кодировок,неверными символами, etc)

собственно вопрос **как сделать проект в UTF?** или **что я [пропустил, не указал, etc]?**

P.S. при использовании чисто 1251 и настроек по дефолту всё пашет, но 1251 не подходит (в будущем хотелось бы перейти на linux с переносом проектов)

Comment: покапайтесь в настройках, там можно выставить кодировку по умолчанию

Comment: @Andreich в каких именно настройках?

Answer (score 6):

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings...
В открывшемся окне Editor -> File Encodings
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Была подобная проблема, настраивал тут - обычно по умолчанию идет utf-8 но иногда бывают неожиданности

[image]

Comment: про то что можно изменить кодировку для чтения файла из текущей вкладки я знаю (кстати в 12.1.6 даже предлагает преобразовать а не только прочитать)

но в том то и проблема! если я использую два  *.java с разными кодировками(UTF+1251), то компилиться всё будет с UTF, и будут ошибки при чтении файла *.java(1251). если даже я свои *.java преобразую в UTF то останутся файлы которые генерирует IDE(их я описал в вопросе)

Answer (score 0):

File>Other settings>Default settings>File encodings

Comment: а чем ваш ответ отличается от [соседнего](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417110/178576)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: может, человек просто не увидел тот вопрос. )

Answer (score 0):

Это баг вот подобное в Intelij RubyMine. Пишите им в баг репорт(с указанием шагов которые привели для воспроизведения).

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206704055-Change-default-encoding-for-Rubymine