# Проблема с кодировкой Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Перестал распознавать русские буквы.

```
System.out.println("Привет");
```

выводит

```
??????
```

Intellij последней версии.

Comment: поменяйте кодировку на utf-8

Comment: Можно подробней? Где поменять? Я работаю с этой IDEA третий день, не знаю что и как.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Intellij-IDEA кодировка в android проекте (UTF and 1251)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264455/intellij-idea-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-utf-and-1251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь или в общих настройках можно изменить кодировку проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]