# вывод программы в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, вывод

После компиляции вместо кириллицы показывает знаки вопросов, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Intellij-IDEA кодировка в android проекте (UTF and 1251)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264455/intellij-idea-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-utf-and-1251)

Comment: И этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441898/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-intellij-idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из за кодировки в IDEA!поменяй его [image: encoding idea]

Answer (score 1):

В правом нижнем углу можно поменять кодировку